# Is this sentence structure correct? I catch myself using this structure a lot

Tags: grammar, punctuation, syntactic-analysis

This is a line from a story I'm writing:
"The blanket had been peeled back, revealing imprints of recent slumber."
Is this correct or should I make another sentence for the second clause?

Comment: What you have is unexceptionable. Don't overthink it.

Comment: It isn't unexceptionable; it's clumsy and the imagery is inaccurate.  True, there are no grammar problems (or, as Jasper Locke wrote, “nothing wrong with the structure”).

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with the structure. It is common in writing and literature, especially at the end. If rewritten into two sentences or conjoined by "and" and 'finitizing' the verb (revealing->reveal), it could be seen as stylistically wordy or clumsy.

It also provides a smoother cause and effect/result:

1. The blanket had been peeled back, (cause)
2. revealing imprints of recent slumber (result)

It's also common in literature in general:

> "Here and there through the smoke, *creeping warily under the shadows of tottering walls*, emerged occasional men and women."
>   (Jack London, "Story of an Eyewitness: The San Francisco Earthquake." Collier's Weekly, May 5, 1906)
>
> "Then he saw the eagles across the distance, two of them, *riding low in the depths and rising diagonally toward him*."
>   (N. Scott Momaday, House Made of Dawn, 1969)

[Source](http://grammar.about.com/od/pq/g/partphraseterm.htm)

To address your header, if you do use this structure a lot, perhaps, you should try to vary it by using a different structure (e.g., infinitive phrase, ***To tell*** me that I didn't earn those badges is a lie.)

Though the construction above is perfectly acceptable, it can be hazardous and lead to hilarity (and ambiguity):

> Oozing slowly across the floor, Marvin watched the salad dressing.
>
> Driving like a maniac, the deer was hit and killed.
>
> Holding a bag of groceries, the roach flew out of the cabinet.

[Source](http://writing.wisc.edu/Handbook/CommonErrors_BestMod.html)

I used ones that are humorous because they illustrate the dangers of the phrase best in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

I vote for a single sentence:

1. the grammar is O.K.
2. two sentences would increase the total word count
3. two sentences would not improve clarity or remove ambiguity